# ASP.NET Function call in Javascript returning HTML code

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to call a serverside function from Javascript.

There is plenty of documentation out there for that, however there is none for the case where `alert()` function produces HTML code instead of what the server side function is meant to return. I have tried it in multiple browsers.

Server side:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Drawing.Layout;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

//needed for SQL access
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;

using System.Net;
using PDFCreator;

namespace theform
{

    public partial class submit : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostBackEventHandler
    {
        public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            functions fun = new functions();
            fun.Main();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //functions fun = new functions();
            //fun.Main();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string RegisterUser(string email, string password)
        {
            string result = "Congratulations!!! your account has been created.";
            if (email.Length == 0)//Zero length check
            {
                result = "Email Address cannot be blank";
            }
            else if (!email.Contains(".") || !email.Contains("@")) //some other basic checks
            {
                result = "Not a valid email address";
            }
            else if (!email.Contains(".") || !email.Contains("@")) //some other basic checks
            {
                result = "Not a valid email address";
            }

            else if (password.Length == 0)
            {
                result = "Password cannot be blank";
            }
            else if (password.Length < 5)
            {
                result = "Password canonot be less than 5 chars";
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <fieldset style="width: 200px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Text="Email Address"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </fieldset>
            <div>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCreateAccount" runat="server" Text="Signup" OnClientClick="Signup();return false;" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Signup() {
            var email = document.getElementById('<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>').value;

            PageMethods.RegisterUser(email, password, onSucess, onError);

            function onSucess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }

            function onError(result) {
                alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
            }
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the HTML being returned? An error page? You can dig deeper by inspecting the XHR req/resp in your browser (dev tools). Hth...

Comment: Here is the HTML returned:  i.imgur.com/F1VRx1x.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing a few settings in your `web.config`, see following link:

http://codeverge.com/asp.net.client-side/pagemethods-not-working-as-intended/260067

Comment: Look at my web.config posted above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the HTTP response message, you can try to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler). I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: I wish to see the string from the function. Instead, it shows a bunch of HTML code, some mine, some not. Others have tested this code and said it works. Is there some sort of network/server issue here?

Comment: Can you attach the HTML Code you are getting from the server please.

Comment: I would suggest to use Jquery Ajax rather than MS ScriptManager.